# Trying to define nested object

Tags: javascript, json, nested

I am pretty new to coding. I am trying to define and store data from an API, but can't manage to define the values that exists nested in another object. Been looking around for a solution but the examples doesn't really work for me.

This is a part of the code:

```
for (var i in json) {

    var TestOrdersXML = <testOrders _key="@testOrderId" operation="insertOrUpdate"/>;

    if (json[i].testOrderId != undefined) TestOrdersXML.@testOrderId = json[i].testOrderId;
    if (json[i].customerId != undefined) TestOrdersXML.@customerId = json[i].customerId;
    if (json[i].installationOrderData.state != undefined) TestOrdersXML.@state = json[i].installationOrderData.state;


   logInfo(" Test order Id: " + json[i].testOrderId + " Customer Id: " + json[i].customerId + " STATE: " + json[i].state);
    //collection.appendChild(TestOrdersXML);
  }
```

The response I get from the log is: Test order Id: 123456 Customer Id: 123456 STATE: undefined.

This is the json I am trying to get:

```
[
    {
        "installationOrderData":{
            "state": "booked"
        },
        "customerId": 123456,
        "testOrderId": 123456
    }
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: By `json[i].state`, do you mean `json[i].installationOrderData.state`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct... Oh I see now .. haha thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are logging " " STATE: " + json[i].state" instead of " " STATE: " + json[i].installationOrderData.state " .